# Android findViewById is returning NULL

Tags: android

sometime I have a strange problem with my xml views and contained sub elements in Android Eclipse SDK.

For example, I have a xml view called main.xml with a LinearLayout and a TextView as only child, with the id *textView1*. Everything works fine for a (long) time. When doing some major code changes, it **might** happen, that `findViewById(R.id.textView1);` starts returning *null*. Recompilation does not change anything. That is strange.

After some time I found a workaround... I copied *main.xml* to *main2.xml* and changed `setContentView(R.layout.main)` to `setContentView(R.layout.main2)` and everything was working fine againg, without changing anything other than the layout reference, even the layout itself was only copied. No content was modified. After the first working run, I can delete *main2.xml* and set the layout back to `R.layout.main`. No more NullPointerException.

Does someone have an idea what is going wrong and how to fix this without doing the stupid copy thing?

Best,
Hacksteak

Comment: This happens to me as well, particularly when I delete a resource or rename it. It generally gets fixed by doing a Project -> Clean and a Refresh.

Comment: That's right, I spent an hour a few days ago before I understood it was an Eclipse bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens to me allot if there are problems with Eclipse, like a force close. What it works for me is cleaning the project until it get all resources and references right back.