# Unable to find components using the findViewById method in Android

Tags: android, layout, nullpointerexception

I'm attempting to create an Activity and unfortunately every time I want to grab one of my XML components it gives me a RunTimeException (NullPointer).

Anytime I use code such as:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myView);    //I get the exception
```

The same happens for any components I attempt to find with that method. I can't quite figure out why. I know it isn't due to the Activity not being in the Manifest because it's the only Activity in the test app I made. (The one set up by default).

Oddly I can still use `setContentView(R.id.myView)`. It just doesn't seem to want to find anything when using the `findViewById` method.

Info that might be of use:

- I am currently using NetBeans as my IDE.
- I have done multiple 'clean and builds' as was suggested in another question. [Android -findViewById question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002945/android-findviewbyid-is-returning-null)

Has anyone run into this issue before? If so, what was the solution?

If need be, I can provide sample code of when this is happening.

Comment: It could be that R.java isn't getting generated properly, how are you generating the R.java file?  Also look at this http://www.matt-reid.co.uk/blog_post.php?id=33

Comment: could you post the onCreate() code where you are using setContentView() and trying to get reference to textView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass in a view ID to `setContentView`, pass in a layout resource ID:

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);
```

If you still have problems, post your layout file.

Answer (score 1):

It is very sure that you R.java is not properly generated.

Delete R.Java in netbeans IDE and Re-build the project.

Hope it resolves your query.